# Java JVM Default Garbage Collector: is it configured the same across different applications?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, benchmarking

Simply as specified in the title.

I ran a test and recorded its memory heap usage pattern over time using JMX. Then I reran my jar file later and studied its memory behavior again. The result was a slightly different memory pattern. In both cases I didn't preconfigure my garbage collector. So I want to know now if two default garbage collectors have the same configurations on the same machine.

If not, how can I ensure that my garbage collector is the same without specifying many parameters? Also what could contribute to my result if not the GC config?

Comment: Even the simplest program consists of code and data that has to be loaded, which may be cached or not or end up at a mechanical device (e.g. a hard drive) in the worst case, so it’s a process with no deterministic timing. Likewise, there is no guaranteed execution time for Java code in general, plus the thread scheduling which is not deterministic. So it should not surprise that executing this code will also have differences in the memory usage pattern in each run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the same application on the same machine, with the same JVM, the heap and GC parameters will be the same.

Ergonomics was a feature introduced way back in JDK 5.0 to try and take some of the guesswork out of GC tuning.  A server-class machine (2 or more cores and 2 or more Gb of memory) will use 1/4 of physical memory (up to 1Gb) for both the initial and maximum heap sizes (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html).  So different machines may have different configurations by default.

To find out exactly what flags you have set, use:
`java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version`

The difference in memory usage pattern is simply the non-deterministic behaviour of your application.  Even with the exact same set of inputs, I doubt you'd see exactly the same memory behaviour just down to so many other OS and hardware effects (cache, core affinity, etc.)